# Datepicker jQuery Plugn Issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using datepicker jquery plugin for wordpress and it works really great besides an issues that u can help me with. When the user choose the day must double click to select it. I would like to be able to select the day with a single click. Year and month works great since they are select options. I am missing the code for removing the double click on day select and i would like to replace it with single click.

Here is my code so far and i would like for someone to use my code and add on that the removing double click and add single click on day select.

Thanks.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker( {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "1917: +nn",
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It seems that your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/xjvvwtmr/

Comment: Thanks for ur answer @lonut but if u look carefully u can see that u click one time on day and the date is set but the day is not changed. If u click fast double click then it will set the correct day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've change your code a bit. You need to get the selected day, month, year a bit differently by using `inst.currentDay`, `inst.currentMonth`, `inst.currentYear`. I hope this helps you:

Working **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xjvvwtmr/2/)**.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "1917: +nn",
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = inst.currentMonth;
    var year = inst.currentYear;
    var day = inst.currentDay;

    var correctDate = $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, day));
    console.log(correctDate);
  }
});
```